# Using subtract in a Spring MongoDB group aggregation

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following aggregation query that works when I use the command line in Mongo.

```
{'$group': 
    { '_id': 
        {'serviceName': '$serviceName'}, 
    'timeAverage': 
        {'$avg': 
            {'$subtract': ['$lastCheckTime', '$enqueuedTime']}
        }
    }
}
```

But as far as I can tell, in Spring MongoDB there is no support for doing "subtract" inside of an avg operation in a group operation.

How would I go about making this work?

Answer (score 3):

You could try projecting the difference field first by using the **[SpEL `andExpression`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.examples.example5)** in the projection operation and then use it in the avg accumulator in the group operation:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project("serviceName")      
        .andExpression("lastCheckTime - enqueuedTime").as("interval")            
    group("serviceName")        
        .avg("interval").as("timeAverage")
);
```

or use the **[`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#exp._S_subtract)** arithmetic aggregation operator which is supported in Spring Data MongoDB as **`minus()`**

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    project("serviceName")      
        .and("lastCheckTime").minus("enqueuedTime").as("interval")
    group("serviceName")        
        .avg("interval").as("timeAverage")
);
```

This translates to following native aggregation operation:

```
[
    {
        "$project": {
            "serviceName": 1,
            "interval": { "$subtract":[ "$lastCheckTime", "$enqueuedTime" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$serviceName",
            "timeAverage": { "$avg": "$interval" }
        }
    }
]
```