# GroupBy data based on date range in spring data mongo db

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, date-range

How can i GroupBy data, based on date range in spring data Mongo db using 
ArithmeticOperators.Subtract

I have wide range of timed data, and i should summarize data, based on average in interval time:

I partitioned data based on interval time and run this aggregation for each interval. this method is too time consuming operation when i use for loop and change start and until throw loop

```
MatchOperation match = match(Criteria.where("type").is(id).andOperator(Criteria.where("time").gt(start),
                Criteria.where("time").lt(until)));
        matchOperationL.add(match);
        GroupOperation as = group("type").avg("value").as("mean");
        ProjectionOperation previousOperation = project("mean").and("type").previousOperation();

        Aggregation avg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match, as, previousOperation);
        AggregationResults<Data2> aggregate = mongotemplate.aggregate(avg, Data1.class, Data2.class);
```

how can i use

> ArithmeticOperators.Subtract

to solve my problem?

my EntityClass

```
public class Data1 {
@Id
private String id;
//value of data
private Number So;

//recorded time
private long time;
}
```

Can any one help me to convert this query to spring data form?

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {$group: { _id:{'$add': {'$trunc': { '$subtract' :[ {'$divide' : ['$time', 15000 ]}, { '$mod' : [{'$divide' :['$time',15000]},1] } ]},'$time'}}, avg : {$avg : "$So"} }}]
```

Comment: @veearm  Because data range may be  grater than one week the result have over than 50000 record. i should summarized data  and return at most 1000 row.   and for each range of data that i summarized them i put average as summarized value. in above method i spited date to multi partition and for each partition i run one aggregation query and finally i merge result.

Comment: @veearm  this question is very like my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660664/using-subtract-in-a-spring-mongodb-group-aggregation

Comment: How is data range identified ? Can you show an example ? What two fields do you subtract ?

Comment: @Veeram  Can you help me and convert this query to spring data form?      db.collection.aggregate([ {$group: {  _id:{'$add': {'$trunc': {  '$subtract' :[ {'$divide' : ['$time', 15000 ]}, { '$mod' : [{'$divide' :['$time',15000]},1] } ]},'$time'}},
avg : {$avg : "$So"}
}}] 
)

Comment: You can transform your query in 2 ways. First you can use `AggregationOperation` to create a group stage. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011355/how-to-write-mongodb-aggregation-group-pipeline-on-part-of-date-timeyear-month/42013776#42013776). Other option to move group id calculation to project stage using spring aggregation operator builder. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783725/how-to-use-sum-and-condition-in-group-using-spring-data-mongodb-aggregation/43851550#43851550). Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Veeram Is exist a way that I execute pure query in spring data? like this   BasicQuery query1 = new BasicQuery("complex aggregate query");
 mongoOps.find(query1, Data.class);

Comment: Aggregate query is not a find query. So you can't do like that. You have two options. First option you can use [`exceuteCommand`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate) in mongotemplate  to pass the all the arguments in single `BasicDBObject`.`BasicDBObject` variable will need a `aggregate` key that will be `BasicDBList` to include all the aggregation stages. Each aggregation stage can be built using `new BasicDBObject("$match", BasicDBObject.parse(match query))` so on to build the aggregation stages list. Second option in next comment.

Comment: Second option is to implement AggregationOperation to each stage.Something like `AggregationOperation matchOperation = new AggregationOperation() {             @Override             public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {                 return new BasicDBObject("$match", BasicDBObject.parse(match query));             }         };`.Repeat for all other stages. Now you can use `Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(matchOperation, ....)` followed by       `mongoOps.aggregate(aggregation, Data.class)`

Comment: @Veeram  Thank you for your very helpful comment. i choose second option and for sort stage this exception    Command failed with error 17312: '$meta is the only expression supported by $sort right now' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "$meta is the only expression supported by $sort right now", "code" : 17312 }

Comment: You are welcome. Try `return new BasicDBObject("$sort", BasicDBObject.parse("{'_id':1}"));` for sort stage. Rest all looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

@Veeram second option is like this:

```
AggregationOperation matchTime = new AggregationOperation() {
        @Override
        public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
            return new BasicDBObject("$match", BasicDBObject
                    .parse("{ 'time': {$gt: " + s + ", $lt: " + e + "} } }"));
        }
    };

    AggregationOperation matchSId = new AggregationOperation() {
        @Override
        public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
            return new BasicDBObject("$match", BasicDBObject
                    .parse("{'sd' : '" + sd + "'}"));
        }
    };
    AggregationOperation groupOperation = new AggregationOperation() {
        @Override
        public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
            return new BasicDBObject("$group",
                    BasicDBObject.parse("{  _id:{   '$trunc': {  '$subtract' :[ {'$divide' : ['$time', " + dist
                            + " ]},{ '$mod' : [{'$divide' :['$time'," + dist
                            + " ]},1] } ]}},avg : {$avg : '$So'}}}"));
        }
    };
    AggregationOperation sortOperation = new AggregationOperation() {
        @Override
        public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
            return new BasicDBObject("$sort", BasicDBObject.parse("{'_id':1}"));

        }
    };

    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchSd,matchTime, groupOperation, sortOperation);
    AggregationResults<Result> aggregate = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, Data.class, Result.class);
```

Comment: @Veeram I got this error failed: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument. I use mongodb version 3.6 and my aggregation is like above answer.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510855/streaming-the-result-of-an-aggregate-operation-using-spring-data-mongodb)